# Kusto query to get correct users counts connected to the server

Tags: kql

there is WVDConnections table in Log Analytics with such data:

| DateTime | User | Session status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09:20:39 | user3 | Completed |
| 09:05:41 | user3 | Connected |
| 09:05:07 | user3 | Started |
| 06:51:58 | user1 | Completed |
| 06:46:22 | user2 | Completed |
| 06:12:40 | user2 | Connected |
| 06:12:18 | user2 | Started |
| 05:36:11 | user1 | Connected |
| 05:35:37 | user1 | Started |

Session status:
Started - user initiated connection.
Connected - user connected.
Completed - user disconnected.

I need a timechart that displays time gaps then there is no connected users (display as 0) and user counts on the server in certain periods.

So in this case if taking 24 hours period from above table:

```
0 connections between 09:20:39 - 24:00:00  
1 connection between 09:05:07 - 09:20:39  
0 connections between 06:51:58 - 09:05:07  
1 connection between 06:46:22 - 06:51:58  
2 connections between 06:12:18 - 06:46:22  
1 connection between 05:35:37 - 06:12:18  
0 connections between 00:00:00 - 05:35:37
```

Now I have only this query

```
WVDConnections
| where TimeGenerated between (datetime(2024-02-26,00:00) .. datetime(2024-02-26,23:59))
| summarize dcount(UserName) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| render timechart
```

But it just counts number of users in 1 hours periods and never display 0 connection on the chart.

How to write the correct kusto query that displays **0 connections and correct user counts then they connects/disconnects**?

Answer (score 1):

this is another interesting one where KQL like all languages like this isn't great at showing you what isn't there.  So you need to give it things that you know from the start, in this case I've assumed a `StartWindow` and `EndWindow`.

I have taken your code and question, added some additional variables and some extra testing source data.  I've added in the source data an entry with just "Connected" (with `//***` for visibility), you may want to comment that line out for testing.

Otherwise hope it helps.

```
let WDConnectionsFaux = datatable(DateTime:datetime, User:string, SessionStatus:string) [
datetime('2024-03-29T09:20:39'), 'user3', 'Completed',
datetime('2024-03-29T09:05:41'), 'user3', 'Connected',
datetime('2024-03-29T09:05:07'), 'user3', 'Started',
datetime('2024-03-29T06:51:58'), 'user1', 'Completed',
datetime('2024-03-29T06:46:22'), 'user2', 'Completed',
datetime('2024-03-29T06:12:40'), 'user2', 'Connected',
datetime('2024-03-29T06:12:18'), 'user2', 'Started',
datetime('2024-03-29T05:36:11'), 'user1', 'Connected',
datetime('2024-03-29T05:35:37'), 'user1', 'Started',
datetime('2024-03-29T15:00:00'), 'user1', 'Started', //Have added in a little extra data for testing
datetime('2024-03-29T15:00:00'), 'user4', 'Connected', //***Only log entry is Connected, assumed 24 hour connection? ***
datetime('2024-03-29T15:30:00'), 'user1', 'Connected', //Duplicate User
datetime('2024-03-29T16:45:00'), 'user1', 'Completed',
datetime('2024-03-29T23:00:00'), 'user5', 'Started', //Session starts late in the window
];
let Units = 1m; //eg 1 minute 'slices'
let StartWindow = floor(datetime('2024-03-29T00:00:00'), Units);
let EndWindow = floor(datetime('2024-03-29T23:59:59'), Units);
let ConstantConnection = WDConnectionsFaux
| where DateTime between (StartWindow .. EndWindow)
| summarize AllSessionStates = make_set(SessionStatus) by User
| where AllSessionStates has_all ('Connected') and array_length(AllSessionStates) == 1 //If all we have is connected assume 24 hour connection
| summarize by User;
let AssumedStarts = WDConnectionsFaux
| where DateTime between (StartWindow .. EndWindow)
| summarize arg_min(DateTime, User) by SessionStatus //Get the first change
| where SessionStatus == 'Completed' //Only care if the first log is Completed
| union (ConstantConnection) //Add in Connected sessions
| extend SessionStatus = 'Started', DateTime = StartWindow; //Create an entry at the beginning of our window as Started
let AssumedCompleteds = WDConnectionsFaux
| where DateTime between (StartWindow .. EndWindow)
| summarize arg_max(DateTime, User) by SessionStatus //Get the last change
| where SessionStatus == 'Started' //Only care if the last log is Started
| union (ConstantConnection) //Add in Connected sessions
| extend SessionStatus = 'Completed', DateTime = EndWindow; //Create an entry at the beginning of our window as Started;
range DateTime from StartWindow to EndWindow step Units //Generate the entireity of possible times in our window
| join kind = leftouter ( //Join in all our assumed and known data
WDConnectionsFaux
| where DateTime between (StartWindow .. EndWindow)
| union (AssumedStarts), (AssumedCompleteds) //Mix our actual data and assumed data back together
| extend DateTime = floor(DateTime, Units)
| where SessionStatus != 'Connected' //If we have Started and Completed does Connected matter?
| partition by User ( //For each User create individual sessions
  order by DateTime asc
  | scan with_match_id=SessionId with (
  step Started: SessionStatus == 'Started' ;
  step Completed: SessionStatus == 'Completed';)
)
| summarize StartedTime = min(DateTime), CompletedTime = max(DateTime) by SessionId = strcat(User, '-', SessionId) //User our SessionId a bit like a key
| mv-expand TimeFrame = range(StartedTime, CompletedTime, Units) to typeof(datetime) //Create the range for the entire Session
| summarize AllSessions = make_set(SessionId) by TimeFrame
) on $left.DateTime == $right.TimeFrame
| project-away TimeFrame
| summarize by NumberOfSessions = array_length(AllSessions), DateTime //Use the SessionIds to count number of concurrent connections
| extend NumberOfSessions = coalesce(NumberOfSessions, 0) //Add zeros in our data
| order by DateTime asc
| render timechart
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, Gyp the Cat, that is a very complicated query, just a question, maybe better would be to eliminate Connected state and have only Started and Completed to have clarity when session started and then completed and simplify the code. And the question why it shows 2 until 5.35 at it was no connections. The first connection started at 5.35 right? Also 12.00 UTC it was no connection but it show as 1? thanks

Comment: Happy to help, and yes it is a complicated query I agree.  If you removed "Connected" how would you track if someone has a session open over the full time period?  ie no Started or Completed.  In addition I did add some additional testing data right at the top which I've commented, if you remove them the results will be much more similar to what you allude to.  With all the test data above user4 had a "permanent" connection through the whole period.  If you comment out that line with the //*** you'll see the difference.